# Leetcode 1155. dictionary based memoization vs LRU Cache

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was solving [leetcode 1155](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-dice-rolls-with-target-sum/) which is about number of dice rolls with target sum. I was using dictionary-based memorization. Here's the exact code:

```
class Solution:
    def numRollsToTarget(self, dices: int, faces: int, target: int) -> int:
        
        dp = {}
        def ways(t, rd):
            if t == 0  and rd == 0: return 1
            if t <= 0 or rd <= 0: return 0
            if dp.get((t,rd)): return dp[(t,rd)]
            dp[(t,rd)] = sum(ways(t-i, rd-1) for i in range(1,faces+1))
            return dp[(t,rd)]
        
        return ways(target, dices)
```

But this solution is invariably timing out for a combination of face and dices around 15*15

Then I found this solution which uses functools.lru_cache and the rest of it is exactly the same. This solution works very fast.

```
class Solution:
    def numRollsToTarget(self, dices: int, faces: int, target: int) -> int:
        from functools import lru_cache
        @lru_cache(None)
        def ways(t, rd):
            if t == 0  and rd == 0: return 1
            if t <= 0 or rd <= 0: return 0
            return sum(ways(t-i, rd-1) for i in range(1,faces+1))
        
        return ways(target, dices)
```

Earlier, I have compared and found that in most cases, lru_cache does not outperform dictionary-based cache by such a margin.

Can someone explain the reason why there is such a drastic performance difference between the two approaches?

Comment: if you would check `if dp.get((t,rd)): return dp[(t,rd)]` as first line in your function then your code would be more similar to version with `lru_cache`. You don't have to check `t == 0, ....` for values which are in `dp`. And `lru_cache` also doesn't check `t == 0, ....`

Comment: python needs some time to access element in dictionary so maybe you should assign sum to local variable - `result = sum(...)` - and later `dp[(t,rd)] = result` and `return result`. This way you will run `dp[(t,rd)]` only once.

Comment: These steps might provide just a marginal improvement but still it times out when I try.

Comment: You could also run `cProfile` first to see your bottleneck and try to optimize it...  I'll post similar for comparison.

Comment: Some cProfile results to share which area are doing `heavy-lifting` and may cause problems. Then another revised `memo` version is profile to compare the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, running your OP code with `cProfile` and this is the report:

- with   ***print(numRollsToTarget2(4, 6, 20))***  (OP version)

You can spot right away there're some heavy calls in `ways` `genexpr` and `sum`.  That's prob. need close examinations and try to improve/reduce.  Next posting is for similar `memo` version, but the `calls` is much less.  And that version has passed w/o timeout.

```
35
         2864 function calls (366 primitive calls) in 0.018 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.018    0.018 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 dice_rolls.py:23(numRollsToTarget2)
   1075/1    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.001 dice_rolls.py:25(ways)
   1253/7    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 dice_rolls.py:30(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.018    0.018 dice_rolls.py:36(main)
       21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:153(debug)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.006 rpc.py:216(remotecall)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:226(asynccall)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.016    0.005 rpc.py:246(asyncreturn)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:252(decoderesponse)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.016    0.005 rpc.py:290(getresponse)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:298(_proxify)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.016    0.005 rpc.py:306(_getresponse)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:328(newseq)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:332(putmessage)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 rpc.py:559(__getattr__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:57(dumps)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 rpc.py:577(__getmethods)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:601(__init__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.016    0.008 rpc.py:606(__call__)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 run.py:412(encoding)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 run.py:416(errors)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.008 run.py:433(write)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:1306(current_thread)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:222(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.016    0.005 threading.py:270(wait)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:81(RLock)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _struct.pack}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _thread.allocate_lock}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _thread.get_ident}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.018    0.018 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.017 {built-in method builtins.print}
    179/1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 {built-in method builtins.sum}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method select.select}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '_acquire_restore' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '_is_owned' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '_release_save' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        6    0.016    0.003    0.016    0.003 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'collections.deque' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'bytes' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'dump' of '_pickle.Pickler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'str' objects}
      201    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'getvalue' of '_io.BytesIO' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'release' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'send' of '_socket.socket' objects}
```

Then I tried to run modified/simplified version, and compare the results.

```
35
         387 function calls (193 primitive calls) in 0.006 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.006 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.006 dice_rolls.py:36(main)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 dice_rolls.py:5(numRollsToTarget)
    195/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 dice_rolls.py:8(dp)
       21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:153(debug)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.002 rpc.py:216(remotecall)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:226(asynccall)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.002 rpc.py:246(asyncreturn)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:252(decoderesponse)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.002 rpc.py:290(getresponse)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:298(_proxify)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.002 rpc.py:306(_getresponse)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:328(newseq)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:332(putmessage)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 rpc.py:559(__getattr__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:57(dumps)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 rpc.py:577(__getmethods)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:601(__init__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.003 rpc.py:606(__call__)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 run.py:412(encoding)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 run.py:416(errors)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.003 run.py:433(write)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:1306(current_thread)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:222(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.002 threading.py:270(wait)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:81(RLock)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _struct.pack}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _thread.allocate_lock}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _thread.get_ident}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.006 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.006 {built-in method builtins.print}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method select.select}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '_acquire_restore' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '_is_owned' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '_release_save' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        6    0.006    0.001    0.006    0.001 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'collections.deque' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'bytes' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'dump' of '_pickle.Pickler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'str' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'getvalue' of '_io.BytesIO' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'release' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'send' of '_socket.socket' objects}
```

The profiling codes are here:

```
import cProfile
from typing import List

def numRollsToTarget(d, f, target):
    memo = {}

    def dp(d, target):
        if d == 0:
            return 0 if target > 0 else 1
        if (d, target) in memo:
            return memo[(d, target)]

        result = 0
        
        for k in range(max(0, target-f), target):
            result += dp(d-1, k)
        memo[(d, target)] = result
        return result 
    
    return dp(d, target) % (10**9 + 7)
    
def numRollsToTarget2(dices: int, faces: int, target: int) -> int:
    dp = {}
    def ways(t, rd):
        if t == 0  and rd == 0: return 1
        if t <= 0 or rd <= 0: return 0
        if dp.get((t,rd)): return dp[(t,rd)]
        
        dp[(t,rd)] = sum(ways(t-i, rd-1) for i in range(1,faces+1))
        return dp[(t,rd)]
        
    return ways(target, dices)

def numRollsToTarget3(dices: int, faces: int, target: int) -> int:
    from functools import lru_cache
    @lru_cache(None)
    def ways(t, rd):
        if t == 0  and rd == 0: return 1
        if t <= 0 or rd <= 0: return 0
        return sum(ways(t-i, rd-1) for i in range(1,faces+1))
        
    return ways(target, dices)
def main():
    print(numRollsToTarget(4, 6, 20))
    #print(numRollsToTarget2(4, 6, 20))
    #print(numRollsToTarget3(4, 6, 20))  # not faster than first



if __name__ == '__main__':
    cProfile.run('main()')
```